# Interactive Plotting using Matplotlib in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am facing issues while plotting in python using matplotlib library. While working in an event loop, the figures are not responding and once the code ends the figures are responding. Any way out to interact with the figures without using the pause command? for example:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import plot, draw, show

def make_plot():
    plot([1,2,3])
    draw()
    print ('continue computation')

print('Do something before plotting.')
# Now display plot in a window
make_plot()

answer = input('Back to main and window visible? ')
if answer == 'y':
    print('Excellent')
else:
    print('Nope')

show()
```

In the above code, if I am asking for user input, then till user presses key figures appear to be not responding, and as soon as we press enter,i.e. code is completed figure is responding but we are no longer inside the code.Please help me with plotting in an event loop

Comment: You cannot use `input()` in a GUI application. You need to use event handlers instead.

Comment: Hi @ImportanceOfBeingErnest i face the same issue even when I am not using gui...for simple plotting also, the problem persists..for example: see the sample code below

Comment: from matplotlib.pyplot import plot, draw, show

def make_plot():
    plot([1,2,3])
    draw()
    print ('continue computation')

print('Do something before plotting.')
# Now display plot in a window
make_plot()

answer = input('Back to main and window visible? ')
if answer == 'y':
    print('Excellent')
else:
    print('Nope')

show()

Comment: The plotting window **is** a GUI.